# How to accept upper and lower case in django restframework Charfilter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a filter for my model, but when the user enters a value to filter, the results belongs exactly to the string introduced by the user. Is there any way that Charfilter accepts upper and lower case? Is it in the argument "lookup_expr"? I've been googling with no suscess. This is my filter class:

```
class ArticuloFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    clave = CharFilter(
        name="clave",
        lookup_expr="contains"
    )

    clave_jde = CharFilter(
        name="clave_jde",
        lookup_expr="contains"
    )

    descripcion = CharFilter(
        name="descripcion",
        lookup_expr="contains"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Articulo
        fields = [
            'clave',
            'descripcion',
            'tipo',
            'clave_jde',
            'estado',
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the `lookup_expr`: `contains` to `icontains`